# Send key commands wirelessly to Mac from Android app

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth, hid

I am looking into developing an Android app that sends key commands to a Mac wirelessly.

To do this I am trying to find a way of using an Android device (either a smartphone or tablet) as a bluetooth keyboard for the the Mac. When a button on the screen of the phone/tablet is pressed, it would send a user assigned set of keystrokes (for example "Command + Shift + A + B") to the Mac.

These keystrokes would then run a keyboard shortcut that the user had already set up in the running application on the Mac (exactly as if the user had pressed "Command + Shift + A + B" on the actual keyboard).

Does anyone know how I would have to go about setting up this bluetooth connection? If any other wireless connection type would be more suitable, which also does not require the installation of software on the Mac please feel free to suggest them also.

Answer (score 1):

This would require certain permissions on a Mac that would not be possible without installing additional software, because essentially you're talking about establishing a remote desktop connection. This is by no means impossible, but frankly, it's already been done. Check out [TeamVeiwer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) and [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/). Both of these allow configuring different keyboard shortcuts between mobile devices and desktops. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there no way of doing this without the installation of additional software at all? I wouldn't know where to start if had to also develop a companion app for the Mac. Is there no way of simply emulating a bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: Well, back in 2011 there was an app called [BlueputDroid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=940511) which attempted to accomplish essentially the same thing you're talking about, and as far as I can tell, it did not require installing additional software on the desktop. However, the app requires the Android device to be rooted, and it reportedly doesn't work on Mac (as well as a myriad of mobile devices). Problems appear to arise when attempting to alter the appearance of your phone's bluetooth "identity". Seems difficult. But perhaps looking into this app a bit more might help?

Comment: Ahh I see, well i'll have a look into that then. Thanks for your help!